# How to allow access to an application for everyone

Tags: iis-7.5

I've set up an application in IIS. In IP and Domain restrictions there's no IP address specified neither for allow nor for deny. When I try to access the application from  outside I get "403 - Forbidden: Access is denied." message. However, I can access another application that is also set up in the same machine IIS. I've looked at the IP and Domain Restrictions of that application and the list is empty. How can I grant the same access to my application as the one that already works?

Note: The server is Windows Server 2008R2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yahoo, I found it. To allow anyone to access an application you should follow these basic steps.:

1. Select the application and on the right side in the IIS section choose IP Address and Domain Restrictions.
2. Doube click on it or choose Open Feature on the rightmost pane which is called Actions
3. Then in the same Actions pane choose Edit feature settings. A dialog box will appear with a combobox. Select Allow. That's all. To deny everyone you'll of course select Deny.

Answer (score 0):

If you set up the site as a Virtual Directory that points to a UNC path, then you will need to set the Physical Path Credentials under Advanced Settings.